# My jsp page doesn't see css styling

Tags: css, jsp

I know that there are many similar issues in google, but I can't find one that help me..

When I include a css file in my JSP page it doesn't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ../../css/car_rental.css">
```

If I try this:

```
<%@ include file="../../css/style.css"%>
```

it throws exception

```
/WEB-INF/view/../../css/style.css" file not found
```

How can I get rid of *WEB-INF/view/* prefix?

P.S. my jsp page is located at */WEB-INF/view/* folder, and my css file at */css/* folder

Comment: Why are you not just using a plain <link> tag to include the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referencing your style sheet via a server side include. The `<%@ include file="../../css/style.css"%>` tag will inject the contents of the named file into the JSP containing the tag, as if it were copied and pasted. It is unlikely your JSP code will need to modify the contents of your cascading style sheet.

Try replacing the `<%@ include file="../../css/style.css"%>` tag with the HTML tag to include your stylesheet.
`<LINK href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: <LINK href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> also doesn't work; but if I put <style>... </style> directly on the page it works. 

P.S. I also tried to write full path: 
<LINK href="http://localhost:8080/CarRental/css/car_rental.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> where http://localhost:8080/CarRental/css/car_rental.css is accessible via browser

Comment: As I understand I should add something like resource mapping paths, and my app won't map url to .css files. But HOW?

Comment: Andrew, can you please show the contents of the filesystem?  for example: CarRental/   CarRental/css/style.css  CarRental/WEB-INF/view/

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk is the css file named style.css or car_rental.css?  if the actual file name is car_rental.css use <LINK href="/css/car_rental.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: it seems that my server use some old version of css: if I comment all car_rental.css my web-pages still remain formated (used old css). I tried to redeploy, reboot server and computer but ni result. How do delete old css from server?

Comment: I noticed that even if delete my .css files, my app use some old .css version. 

So, I found answer to my own question: it's need to clear browser cache and the new .css version will work

Thanks all for replies

Answer (score 0):

`<%@ include file="XYZ" %>` statically includes the content of your file as part of compiled servlet response.
So even if it successfully finds the CSS file, its content will be treated as normal text and will be flushed in response.
This means that your page will simply display the content of CSS and there wouldn't be any styling that would actually occur

You need to use the `link` tag in the `head`. It directs the browser to apply the style.

Also, relative paths do not work in `include`, as you can see from the error.

Use:

```
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I tried <%@ include file="XYZ" %> because my <LINK href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> doesn't work. It seems my application map url path to my .css and can't find it.

Comment: As I understand I should add something like resource mapping paths, and my app won't map url to .css files. But HOW?

Comment: Ok try placing your css file within the same directory where your jsp is present (view directory) and then use <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">. If this works then clearly the issue is with the way you are giving relative path.

Comment: It seems that my server use some old version of css: if I comment all car_rental.css my web-pages still remain formated (used old css). I tried to redeploy, reboot server and computer but ni result. How do delete old css from server?

Comment: I noticed that even if delete my .css files, my app use some old .css version. 

So, I found answer to my own question: it's need to clear browser cache and the new .css version will work

Thanks for replies

Comment: @AndrewMelnuk seems like you were testing on IE. When developing web pages (even .Net web apps) you should try it on 2 or 3 different browsers. IMO you should make your tests on Chrome, Firefox and IE, being IE the most PITA. I had a similar issue long time ago, solved using this post: [How to disable cache in InternetExplorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2755800/1065197).