# Is it possible to auto refresh Outlook javascript plugin

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm loading outlook plugin from a manifest file served through an URL.

The problem that I'm facing is that the plugin doesn't update immediately. 
Increasing the version in the manifest is not sufficient. I tried to compare client and server versions on plugin init and do a reload but this doesn't seem to produce the desired effect either.

So, Is there a reliable way to update the plugin after source changes? Could it be a cache of some sort that I need to invalidate?

Comment: Is this will be helpful ... [Cleaning office add-in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586353/cleaning-office-add-in-cache/43589705#43589705)?

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly? Did you change your manifest and not seeing new ui/functionality in outlook, or did you change your add-in (HTML/CSS/JS) and not seeing the new ui/functionality in the add-in?

Comment: HTML, css, js update does not trigger the new UI functionality. I only had expectations that when manifest version changes it will automatically refresh the add-in UI. Actually I believe that I fix it. And Slava, my fix is following this thread.

Comment: @user732456 Yes, updates for HTML, CSS, JS would be the same as for regular website, you would need to control cache of those resources.

Comment: As @SlavaIvanov said, you need to clean your cache. In Office Desktop you can also [force IE to reload page every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755800/how-to-disable-cache-in-internetexplorer-8). In browser you can do hard refresh (usually Shift + F5)